# jQuery .val() return empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to sum the values of a column table, each time it gets updated. So for that I have this function, that gets executed each time the table inserts or deletes a row, but for now, it's just sending the value to the console:

```
function update_price(){
  $("#table-content tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("div").val());
  });
}
```

The HTML code associated with it looks like this:

```
<tbody id="table-content">
     <tr class="table-content-line">
        <td>9789898818386</td>
        <td>Fale Menos, Comunique Mais</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="1" class="auto form-control price" value="12" step=".01">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <span class="remove-action">
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
            </span>
        </td>
     </tr>
     ...
</tbody>
```

For some odd reason, when I use `.html()` instead of `.val()`, it returns me the HTML code for the user input, but the same doesn't happen when I use `.val()`.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion, maybe I'm doing something wrong and I didn't checked yet.

Thanks,
mikeysantana

Comment: Regarding to docs for val and html val is trying to get value from value attribute by default, but html on opposite trying to get all content of tags laying beneath selected. In your example you are trying to get the value of value-attribute of the td-tag (but it cannot be done, because it doesn't have one), but html works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to swap `$(this).find("div").text()` with `$(this).find("div input").val();`

The div actually don't contain any text, even though the input is inside it. So you have to target the `input` to get the value

**demo**

```js
function update_price() {
  $("#table-content tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("div input").val());
  });
}

update_price();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="table-content">
    <tr class="table-content-line">
      <td>9789898818386</td>
      <td>Fale Menos, Comunique Mais</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group"><input type="number" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="1" class="auto form-control price" value="12" step=".01"></div>
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span class="remove-action"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span></td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Val() is used for html form elements.  Use text() instead for non form elements.

Comment: The OP **is** using `text` (despite the title of the question).

Comment: Right -- because they're targeting the wrong element, as [Carsten points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790962/157247).

Comment: ah ok nm, tried to give a quick answer from my phone and obviously failed. lol